# Netplan doesn't configure VLAN on hotplug of underlying link

Tags: linux-networking, vlan, netplan

We have the following netplan configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
    ens9: {}
  vlans:
    ens9.4000:
      id: 4000
      link: ens9
      addresses: [ "a.a.a.a/29", "aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::aaaa/64" ]
      gateway4: "a.a.a.1"
      gateway6: "aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::1"
```

If the maschine boots up with both network devices, everything works fine:

- `ens9` comes up without any address
- `ens9.4000` also comes up and gets configured

If I detach the device named `ens9` everything works as expected and both interfaces go down and vanish.

If I attach the device again, only `ens9` comes up. `ens9.4000` isn't created anymore. The same happens if the maschine comes up with one network device and the second on is hotplugged afterwards.

`ens9.4000` is only created if `netplan apply` is called.

Are there any additional settings we are missing?

All this happens on an up to date Ubuntu 18.04.2LTS installation.

**Update:**

For the solution meanwhile in production I replaced `netplan.io` / `systemd-networkd` with `ipupdown`. Adding one somewhat special line did the trick:

```
allow-hotplug ens9 ens9.4000
```